# Server client Remoting

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

I am reading from server

```
 MessageTable msg = (MessageTable)Activator.GetObject(typeof(MessageTable), portFormat, WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

if server is running then it return msg object with values and methods.

it never returns null msg,whether server is running or not,
but when server is not available then  calling it's method it throws exception,
then how to check server is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find the method that allows you to check whether the server is responding, what if the server goes offline between your call to IsOnline() and the call to the method you want to call?

I think that you should handle this exception everywhere you make a remote call.

If you still want to find a way to know whether the server is online, you can add a Ping() method to your MessageTable class that does nothing. You may also check within the [RemotingServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.aspx) class if you find something that helps. Maybe with the RealProxy...